# @Schedule in spring boot will not run on dates which we provided

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

```
@Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * ?")
public void startQuery(){
    try{
      //some code
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

1. How to send dynamic list to @Schedule.
2. `@Scheduled` will run on specific dates which we provided.
3. `@Scheduled` in spring boot will not run on dates which we provided.

In cron expression I want to send list and which dates i want to exclude.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: `cron` can take a SpEL expressoin to obtain something from the properties. This is not fully dynamic. If you want something like that, use Quartz instead of `@Scheduled` for more control. Or manually do the scheduling by submitting tasks to a `TaskScheduler` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In @Scheduled annotation you cannot use dynamic values, but it is not a problem, because you have another approach for this like this code sample:

```
ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
scheduler.initialize();
loadCrons()

private void loadCrons() {
  String cron = <read your cron from somewhere>
  scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        // do your stuff here
     }
  }, new CronTrigger(cron);
}
```

If your crons are changed and you want to reload them, you have to do:

```
scheduler.shutdown();
scheduler.initialize();
loadCrons();
```

Done.